# Rails - how to use request referrer to limit access to a view based on referrer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been looking around for this but can't seem to find a solution for what I'm trying to do.

I have a 'thankyou' view routed from the custom controller action. I want to restrict access to this view to only the case where the user came from the view where the user submitted the form since I don't want users to be able to navigate directly to this view.

How would I write the controller code to accomplish this in the custom controller action?

Comment: The referrer can be spoofed, so make sure you don't have any side effects in your thankyou unless you're explicitly checking he db for the completed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller you can do:

```
def thankyou
  if request.referrer != "http://mysite.com/myformpage"
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Invalid access"
  end
end
```

Or you can create a before_filter for this action with the same logic